# Extension problem of fractional laplacian and Fourier transform of $L^1_\text{loc}$ function?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-transform, fractional-calculus

I have understand the proof oh the lemma 4.1.9 "SOME NONLOCAL OPERATORS AND EFFECTS DUE TO NONLOCALITY" by C.Bocur, there is a [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.00953.pdf). In this paper, we define, for $u\in L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the space $X_u$ of all function $V\in W^{1,1}_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}_+)$, such that the map: $y\mapsto V(x,y)$ is in $C^0([0,\infty))$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and: $V(x,0)=u(x)$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Now let $u\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, let $V\in X_u$, such that:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}_+} y^a|\nabla_{(x,y)}u(x,y)|^2\,dx\,dy<\infty. \tag{1} $$
By (1) we have that: $\nabla_xV(x,y)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, for a.e. $y\in (0,\infty)$, hence i can use the Fourier transform wrt $x$, in the proof then the authors write:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}(\nabla_xV(x,y))(\xi)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\nabla_xV(x,y)e^{-ix\cdot \xi}\,d\xi\\&
=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}i\xi V(x,y)e^{-ix\cdot \xi}\,d\xi\\&
=i\xi \mathcal{F}(V(x,y))(\xi)
\end{align}
i don't understand how to obtain the above chain of equality, moreover i have that $V(\cdot,y)\in L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, what sense have $\mathcal{F}(V(x,y))$??? Then i don't how to interpret and prove that:
$$ \mathcal{F}(\partial_yV(x,y))(\xi)=\partial_y\mathcal{F}(V(x,y))(\xi)  $$
with the above hypothesis. Any help would appreciated.